# designing FIR narrowband pass filter using windowing technique

Tags: digital-filters

I m designing FIR narrowband pass filter using windowing technique. is bandpass filter is same as narrowband pass filter? I m not finding any good article on this.

Comment: i suppose your *"narrowband pass filter"* might have been intended to read as *"narrow bandpass filter"*.

Comment: A narrow band pass sounds like a resonator (?) Which equation are you using to specify it's frequency response? What are the specifications of the filter?

Comment: this is for audio application. the sampling frequency is 44.1kHz, higher and lower cut off frequency is 490Hz and 510Hz respectively.

Answer (score 1):

At 44.1 kHz sampling frequency, an FIR (and possibly also linear phase) digital filter with a pass band of 20 Hz would require very large number of taps. If this is not an issue for you then the design is straight forward by the windowing method. You can use Kaiser window design principle to find the minimum length of a Kaiser window that meets your design criteria (namely the maximum pass and stop band ripples, and the transition band width).

The following OCTAVE / MATLAB commands design a very narrow band bandpass FIR filter,specified by its parameters according to your only given cirteria.
The filter length is not unique, you can play with it to find the minimum
that meets your other criteria (if there are any).

```
Fs = 44100;        % Sampling Frequency
fc1 = 490;         % cutoff frequency 1
fc2 = 510;         % cutoff frequency 2

L = 20000;         % length of the FIR filter
h = fir1(L , 2*[fc1,fc2]/Fs ,'bandpass');    % bandpass FIR filter.

figure,freqz(h,1,L);
title('Frequency response of the FIR filter');
```

and the result is: (I've zoomed into the pass band frequency region to observe it clearly...)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, I want to reduce the no of taps because I want to use for multiple higher and lower cutoff frequencies i.e 8

Comment: You can use IIR filter then. It will subtsantially reduce the number of taps, however, its phase response will be nonlinear.

Comment: how if I use CIC filter?

Comment: CIC is a very special class of filters designed for efficient resampling (interpolation and decimation). I'm not sure if it can be configured into arbitrary filter specifications or whether your application can be implemented through a resampling operation. A simple second order IIR will outlaw any other filter, except its nonlinear phase. Note that for most audio applications a nonlinear phase will not be an issue. But it depends.